# Do beings killed by Lord Shiva get Moksha?

Tags: shiva, moksha

Do any of the  Hinduism scriptures say that someone was killed by Lord Shiva and thus he got Moksha?

Comment: That's not killing. Shiva gave Moksha to many people but they got only after experiencing Prarabda karma (Karma of present life).

Comment: Shiva is Kaal not a person that kills physically, he is the destroyer. And even if you are killed by Shiva or anyone else, No one will get Moksha. you do what ever you can but the karma which is already done, you will have to face the consequences

Comment: @Rishi Rudra Bhagavan kills and grants moksha..thats a blessing   similarly Viswanatha Bhagavan also gives moksha to anyone who dies in Kashi..BTW you are not much active these days?

Comment: @Rickross I went for 10 Days Vipassana Course..:) Then its very easy to get moksha, i would like to spend my last days in kashi :D

Comment: @Rishi Yes easy..but not many people know about this..those who know don't have faith..so eventually not many people dies in Kashi..so eventually not many people get moksha ..But Kashi is the foremost among all the Mokshapuris..

Answer (score 6):

Anyone or any being killed by Shiva attains Shivatva (Shiva Himself) or Moksha. This becomes evident when we see the mantra given for animal sacrifice (Balidana) in KulArnava Tantram (one of the most authoritative ShAkta Agama).

As you might be knowing that sacrificing animals for Deva , Pitru Yajnas has been adjudged as legal in all Hindu Scriptures.

But this sacrifice has to be done only as prescribed in Scriptures. Usually the sacrificial animal is infused & worshiped with some mantras before the sacrifice is performed , so that it attains higher heavens as a reward of sacrificing its life.

In Mahanirvana Tantram (another Shakta Agama), a different mantra, called the Pashu Gayatri , is mentioned. This mantra has to be spoken into the animal's ears before performing the sacrifice and it serves a similar purpose.

Sacrifices which are done without the use of such prescribed mantras takes the performer  to hell.

The mantra given in KulArnava says- Hey animal know that , since you are being killed by Shiva , hence you are attaining Shivahood (i.e moksha).

> **Shivotkrittamidam Pindamatastvam** **ShivatAm Gataha** |
>
> Tadbudhyasva Paso Tvam MAshivastvam Shivohas Hi ||

### Meaning

> **You are being killed (cut) by Shiva. Hence , you will attain Shiva (moksha)**. Hey animal,know this. You are not Ashiva. You are Shiva
>   only.
>
> **KulArnava Tantram , Chapter 5 ,Verse 50.**

The previous verse says one who does not worship the animal with gandha-akshata-pushpa along with this mantra, before the sacrifice, goes to hell.

I agree that this is an indirect approach  but this is the most i could gather for the time being.

Comment: going through these verses what I infer is this is Brahman yajna. One must not be identified with the body, mind or anything otherwise the animal would be killed by a body & mind, not Shiva & thus result in the sin or karmic debt.

Comment: @Rohit That is the whole purpose of using the mantra..If that mantra is used in the ritual then its Shiva whos killing and thereby releasing the animal from bondage..otherwise its a case of killing which takes both the performer and the animal downwards..

Comment: Possibly because one can argue why not to kill anyone chanting that mantra? It is like Muslims beheading saying/chanting "Allahuakbar" .

Comment: @Rohit If that is the case then he does not have faith in the words of Shiva in mantras or in scriptures..anyways never mind..

Comment: Haha @Rickross I've voted this answer because I grasped the essence of this. :) why would I mind. Lord Shiva's word are ultimate authority.

Comment: @Rohit Yes i know..i meant "i didn't mind the downvote" :)

Answer (score 0):

The concept of Moksha is described differently in different scriptures. Some Vaishnava schools take that word to mean exclusively Vaikuntham. And in Upanisads Moksha is also identified with liberation in general as opposed to specific abode of Lord Shiva or Lord Vishnu.

I don't know of any reference in the Puranas that clearly say one way or the other. So I will have to say it depends on which definition of Moksha one accepts. If you take it to mean Vaikuntham like some Vaishnavas sects and schools do, then you have to accept their take that only Lord Sriman Narayana can grant Moksham.

If you take a broader interpretation of that meaning `liberation` in general, then you can take that Lord Shiva can grant Moksham, as implied by Upanisads (Kaivalya, Svetasvatara..)